# Why in this list i am getting maximum as [3]?

Tags: python, list

```
test2_list = [[], [3], [1,2], [2,4], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
maxList = max((x) for x in test2_list)
```

I am getting output as `[3]`, but it should be `[2,3,4]`.

Comment: When two lists are compared, it starts with the first element; if they are the same, then it proceeds to the second one, etc. So `[3]` is the maximum in this case.

Comment: Why do you think `[2,3,4]` should be the answer? What is the rule that tells you that this is "greater" than the other elements? How exactly do you want to compare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking to compare based on the sum given your expected output and input given.

The reason for the output you got was well given in the comment by alaniwi although you're looking to use the `key` arg for `max`

```
maxList = max(test2_list, key=sum)
```

Comment: How did you guess that O_O